# Page Layout - Parent -> Child - > Grand Child

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

Is it possible to display Parent -> Child -> Grand Child -> Great Grand Child Details in Parent Detail Page Layout. Out Of the Box it seems only Parent -> Child be displayed.

In case if this feature is not possible OOB without defining direct relationships, Could this design be achieved via Visual Force? If so could Standard controllers be used for CRUD operations?

Answer (score 3):

We can move five levels up from child to parent .This property we can utilize to achieve this out of box .

1)Create a lookup on the Great Grand Child to the Parent

2)Use workflow to populate the lookup with the parent (Trace from Grand Child and roll Up the Parent Id)

3)Once the lookup is established you can see Great Grand Child as related list of parent .

update:

Its possible through custom visualforce page easily . Standard controller alone will not work.You may have to go for an extension controller .Also inline visualforce is an option as well.

Comment: Thanks Mohith, I would like to have all the data as related list (Parent at the top and Child through GG Child as related lists) moreover defining a Lookup relation just to bring all related data in the Parent Detail Pagelayout is not an option. Is it possible via custom VF page? In this case can I leverage the Standard controllers for CRUD operations?

Comment: @Shibucrm Updated the answer .You will need to write an extension controller